# How do you convert KMS licensed windows 7 to MAK licensed?

Tags: windows-7, licensing, volume-license

I have Windows 7 Business/Enterprise that are automatically configured to use KMS licensing.

How do I convert it to MAK mode licensing?  In the past I did this with `slmgr` however I forgot the command.

Comment: If you just run "slmgr" without arguments it will supply you with all of the available switches. Maybe "-upk" is what you need?

Answer (score 2):

On the computer you're moving to the MAK key:

1. From an elevated command prompt run 'slmgr /rearm', reboot
2. Enter new key from the System Properites window. (To get to the System Properties window - Win + E, choose System Properties in the tool bar, scroll to the bottom and click 'Change product key') or Windows might prompt for activation upon reboot.

slmgr /dlv will provide you with current activation information.

Comment: -1 This does not solve the issue of converting from a computer in "KMS" mode to "MAC" mode.  I tested this myself.

Comment: @makerofthings - you're right, I forgot about the need to tell the machine to forget the current activation via the slmgr tool.

Comment: ... let me know if you know how to use slmgr to convert to MAC mode... I can't find the switch...

Comment: slmgr /? will give you all the commands.  /rearm allows the machine to be set to a fresh activation point.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I ran into this issue with a W2019 server.  Here are the commands I used from elevated cmd prompt.

Step 1. Uninstall Key

```
slmgr /upk
```

Step 2. Clear the Key from the registry

```
slmgr /cpky
```

Step 3. Set the new Key replace the X's with your MAK key

```
slmgr /ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```